# What color is behind a transparent div?

Tags: html, css

In a web browser, if I have a div that is transparent (rgba(0,0,0,0)), and I have no other divs behind it, what color will appear?  Essentially what color is the background of a web browser?  (I'm assuming it's white).

A few followup questions:

- Is the background color mandated by any CSS or HTML specifications?
- If it's not mandated, in reality is it always white?
- If it's not mandated, is there any way that I can programatically detect what the browser background color is?

I'm doing this entirely for mobile devices if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background color of browsers is almost always white. One situation where that would be different would be if the user has customized their browser using some sort of plugin to change the colors. Best bet would be to set the background color yourself, that way you know it will always be the same.

Comment: Do you know if plugins currently exist for mobile phones to change the browser background color? If so, which ones?   (Because, unfortunately, I can't control what the background color is...long story)

Comment: Honestly, on mobile phones I wouldn't worry about it too much. I'm pretty certain that the user would need a jailbroken(rooted) phone in order to make a customization like that, unless they're using a 3rd party browser with that option built in(I don't know of any).

Answer (score 5):

It's entirely up to the browser, but most (all browsers) have a default stylesheet which has a white body background.  So unless otherwise stated, the default background color is white.

Some browsers have a user definable stylesheet where the user can override the default styles of the browser.

More info about Chrome's user stylesheet: https://superuser.com/questions/594358/modify-chrome-user-agent-stylesheet

And for Mozilla Firefox: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss

Not quite sure about IE here.

Yes, you can programmatically check which styles are currently active on any given element, including the background color.

Comment: Do you know of any way to change the stylesheet on a mobile phone?

Comment: No, I doubt that mobile browsers allow that kind of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is white by default. If you'd like it to be otherwise you would declare that in your CSS.